# Media in CSS are not working with max width

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I;m trying media query in scss but is not working. I have code like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<style>
body {
  background: red;
}

@media (min-width: 460px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 459px) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}
</style>
```

now no media query is working for width 459px and background is red... (black is on max 458 and yellow on 460)
but when I changed to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<style>
body {
  background: red;
}

@media (min-width: 460px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 460px) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}
</style>
```

then black background is working for 459px but on 460px two media queries are working...
how to fix that on max-width I will have only black background and on min-width only yellow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently: Define a general rule first and then one media query for smaller screens, like this:

```
body {
  background: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}
```

Or the other way round, using a mobile-first approach:

```
body {
  background: black;
}

@media (min-width: 460px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Both ways there is certainly *no* width where two seetings would collide, and no width where *no* setting would apply at all.